# Css target custom inline tag

Tags: html, css

I am just wondering if its possible targeting an element with CSS via it's attributes. Fo example, can I target `current_room` where the value is `1` with only CSS?

```
<body id="id-43" current_room="1">&nbsp;</body>
```

I tried this, but none of them worked:

```
body[attribute = value]

body[current_room = 1] {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

I do not want to target the `id` just for anyone giving that suggestion, I have my reasons.

Comment: try with `body[current_room="1"]`

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript ...

Comment: @CBroe indeed, I edited it to make it html/css relevant instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last selector is almost correct, you just need to remove the space, as the `body` actually holds that attribute, and wrap the value in quotes:

```css
body[current_room="1"] {
  background-color: #DCC;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body current_room="1"></body>
</html>
```

*However* it should be noted that `current_room` is not a valid attribute for the `body` element, and as such is making your HTML invalid which may have unforeseen effects in some browsers. Using a `data-*` attribute would fix this issue.

Comment: thanks, was missing the double quotes , ish. This worked --> `body[current_room ="1"]`

Comment: The more important issue was the space between `body` and `[current_room...]`, as that is a descendant selector. Glad you got it working, though.

Comment: spaces in attributes `[ ]` do not really matter, the real problem with the 2nd code was the quotes. But It's true that the first code (`body [attribute = value]`) is not the same as it will target descendants with such attribute. However, your first sentence doesn't make it clear since it talks only about the second code.

Comment: I get what you say, but i did not have a space, although it looked like that on stack. The quotes saved me. Thanks @Rory McCrossan

Comment: And note that even though it's bad practice, quotes are mandatory only with values starting with some characters such as numeric values and `#` and maybe others... https://jsfiddle.net/q4Lkcya0/